# Echo objects in Powershell with two different AD objects in them results them being put in the same table

Tags: powershell

I have two objects from an AD query in two variables, when I echo them they always end up in the same table. Very anoying.

For example

```
Echo "Users:"
$InactiveUsers | select name

Echo "Computers:"
$InactiveComputers | select name, lastlogondate
```

This should give me this result

```
Users:
name
----
John

Computers:
name                              lastlogondate
----                              -------------
JohnComputer                      1.1.2011
```

But instead I get it like this

```
Users:
name
----
John
Computers:
JohnComputer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your script is outputting more than one type of object (three in fact).  If you truely want to throw out the objects and just want tables, do this.

```
Write-Host "Users:"
$InactiveUsers | Select name | Out-Host

Write-Host "Computers:"
$InactiveComputers | Select name, lastlogondate | Out-Host
```